# Не работает запрос UPDATE php

Tags: php, mysql, update

Не работает запрос UPDATE, данные не изменяются.
Переменные существуют, через echo проверял, подключение к базе данных тоже, другие запросы выполняются.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `ideas` SET `login` = ".$_POST['name']." WHERE `id` = ".$_POST['id']."");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//защита от XSS атаки и замусоренности    
$name = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']))), 0, 24 );
//Самое длинное русское имя - Константин - 10 символов, на лат.= 20
$id = (int) abs($_POST['id']);//только целое положительное
```

*А если у Вас уже есть соединение с базой, то лучше так:

```
$name = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']))), 0, 24 );
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);//от SQL инъекции
$id = (int) abs($id);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);//можно без этого - в этом случае

$sql = "UPDATE `ideas` SET `login`='$name' WHERE `id`='$id'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Ну, а вообще, как указали, лучше так (просто для интереса)(PDO):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // устанавливаем PDO режим ошибки на исключение
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE ideas SET login='$name' WHERE id='$id'";

    // Подготавливаем запрос
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // Выполняем запрос
    $stmt->execute();

    // Выводим сообщение об успешном апдейте 
    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " Все хорошо";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
```

Процедурный:

```
// Создаем соединение
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Проверяем соединение
if (!$conn) {
    die("Соединение не удалось: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE ideas SET login='$name' WHERE id='$id'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Запись успешно обновлена";
} else {
    echo "Ошибка при обновлении: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

MySQLi объектно-ориентрированный:

```
// Уст. соединение
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Проверяем его
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Не удалось соединиться: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

 $sql = "UPDATE ideas SET login='$name' WHERE id='$id'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Запись успешно обновлена";
} else {
    echo "Ошибка при обновлении записи: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: strip_tags удаляет только теги, кавычки внутри строки останутся, приведут к SQL-инъекции и взлому сайта. Если уже и пользоваться устаревшим 10 лет назад расширением mysql_ то как минимум использовать mysql_real_escape_string(). А вообще надо переходить минимум на mysqli (лучше PDO) и использовать подготовленные выражения и привязку параметров

Comment: @Mike - да, лучше по-новому, но что в условиях ТС записано, из того и исходил. Думается, далее уже можно будет ему поставить самому все и вся, если будет на то желание.

Comment: Но исходя из условий mysql_real_escape_string() единственно верное решение по экранированию

Comment: @Mike - благодарю, поправил.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Но меня интересует конкретно почему мой запрос не срабатывает? Инъекции, mysqli пока что не нужны.

Comment: $_POST['name'] как я понял, использовать нельзя?

Comment: )Пожалуйста. Можно - уберите точки конкатенации и вставляйте без них в одинарных кавычках.